# I want to find percentage change of Open Interest for every Scrip in the table (previous day's Open Interest value being the base value) in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
 Trade_date  | Scrip    | Open_Interest | Change_in_OI | Underlying |
+------------+----------+---------------+--------------+------------+
| 2020-03-16 | ACC      |       2669600 |      -346800 |     1133.4 |
| 2020-03-17 | ACC      |      12293200 |      -376400 |     1124.7 |
| 2020-03-16 | RELIANCE |      31975000 |       -17000 |     1015.7 |
| 2020-03-17 | RELIANCE |      31302000 |      -673000 |       1008 |
```

for example the output can be

```
|SCRIP   | % Change_in_OI |

|ACC     | -0.14          |
|RELIANCE| -0.02          |
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? This is **critical** for any MySQL question. Also, could you please provide your table structures as DDL and your data as DML? I played around with the numbers a litte and can't get -0.14 - what do you divide by what and then multiply by 100 to get that percentage? p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: MySQL version 8.0.

Comment: For calculating % change, you can take the difference of two values and divide by the initial value i.e ((31302000 - 31975000) / 31975000) equals to  -0.02 then multiply by 100.

Comment: If you do the same calculation for the ACC scrip, you get 360%? Is there a 1 missing from the beginning of the open_interest value for the 16th of March?

Comment: @ Verace. I am very sorry for ACC's % change in OI. You are correct it should be ((12293200 - 2669600) / 2669600) equals to 3.6 multiply by 100

Comment: Could you edit the data please using the `edit` link under the question? And at the same time, could you provide DDL (`CREATE TABLE blah (...);`) and DML (`INSERT INTO blah VALUES (...);`) scripts - possibly as a [`fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=3f5b919474ae4339088e6f8a721780b9)? It is also **imperative** that you provide the version of MySQL that you are using - use the `Edit tags` link to add the version.

Comment: This is the last time I write this: please put the scripts **in the question**! Also, please update the question with your **version of MySQL**. Use the [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/262199/edit) link below the question!

Comment: **No!** Edit the **question** and put the DDL (above) and DML (where?) scripts in there - not as a comment - you want **all** the necessary information to be in the question, the whole question and nothing but the question! Having a fiddle is good (not yet...) but you must include everything in the question - link rot!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
  y.Trade_date,x.Scrip, 
  (((y.Open_Interest - x.Open_Interest)/x.Open_Interest)*100)
     AS Change_in_OI from stock_future x 
JOIN stock_future y 
  ON y.Scrip = x.Scrip 
  AND y.Trade_date = '2020-03-17' 
WHERE x.Trade_date = '2020-03-16';
```